# Can I make an android app using html that recieves and stores values entered by the user?

Tags: android, html, phonegap-build

Basically, I'm trying to make use of this website called PhoneGap that recives html codes and converts them into mobile applications.
So I'm trying to make an application that tells you how much money you owe people and how much money people owe you.
IS this possible?

Comment: html is just a markup language for describing the appearence of websites there is no way of converting such code into a "mobile application". I think you should precise your question.

Comment: Maybe you haven't looked up PhoneGap. It actually converts your HTML code into Android, iOS and other platform.

Answer (score 1):

HTML alone isn't enough to develop your application. It's a simple mark-up language and unable to create any real functionality. But HTML if used together with javascript (which adds the required functionality) will work great for building what you mentioned.

So if, for any reason, you'd prefer to not develop a standard native application (one which is installed locally on a user's device), then another option is to build a web-based application. These have much in common with typical websites (though optimized for mobile devices) and are generally easier to build. Another advantage is that they can run on almost any device that has a browser installed, and therefore not tied to any one specific OS, such as Android. Web applications - despite not being installed on the user device - can none the less make use of local storage to save data. This is one example for when javascript is needed.

Here is a great resource for learning about javascript: http://www.w3schools.com/js/

Comment: It sounds like you are unaware of Phonegap. It for the creation of hybrid apps. Theses are not simply web apps.

Answer (score 0):

You should read about HTML5 and hybrid apps. A hybrid app is what you are after.

Yes, you can use html to build an app with Phonegap, but you'll need JavaScript too.

I suggest the following technologies for you: Ionic, Angularjs and localStorage for recording the data.